# Obfuscate only one flavour

Tags: android, proguard, android-productflavors

How would i go about obfuscating just one flavour.

Unfortunately flavour 2 relies on a module (jar) that uses some duplication of classes, and i cannot obfuscate it due to the way it is set up. (3rd party) So wish to skip obfuscating the flavour.

I do not seem able to define minifyENabled false in the flavours section, or add the flavour to the build section.

Note, there are actually 6 flavours in total. The desire is to pick and choose flavours that should be obfuscated

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavour1{
            applicationId "uk.co.company.flavour1"
        }
        flavour2{
            applicationId "uk.co.company.flavour2"
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as there is not present `minifyEnabled` in [`ProductFlavor`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html) DSL object, then you have to create another buildType, e.g. `releaseMinified` along with standard `release`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    releaseMinified {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}

productFlavors {
    minifiableFlavor{}
    nonMinifiableFlavor{}
}
```

And enable this build type only for the flavor that needs that:

```
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name.equals('releaseMinified') && !variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('nonMinifiableFlavor')) {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    } else if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release') && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name.equals('nonMinifiableFlavor')){
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}
```

Then you'll end up with:

[image: Build types]

Comment: Where should this `android.variantFilter` be placed in?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv, inside app module's `build.gradle` file.